# Nested Brackets in Python using stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

Return 0 if not nested
Return 1 if nested

I don't know what's not working on the code below. It is returning 1 even for unbalanced brackets.

```
#from codility
def solution (S):
    B =[]
    
    if len(S) == 0:
        return 1
    for i in range (0,len(S)):
        if S[i] == "(" or S[i] == "[" or S[i] == "{":
            B.append(S[i])
        else: 
            return 0
        if (S[i] == ")" and B[-1]!= "(") :
            return 0
        if (S[i] == "}" and B[-1]!= "{") :
            return 0
        if (S[i] == "]" and B[-1]!= "[") :
            return 0
        else:
            B.pop()

        if len(B)==0:   
            return 1
```

Comment: This code can't run at all, `elif:` is a syntax error.

Comment: add a static linter to your editor such as [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) to catch this sort of issue!

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry it is supposed to be else.

Comment: What is your question ? Is it to check for nested brackets or un-balanced brackets ?

Comment: @Ram return 1 if nested and 0 is unbalanced

Comment: What to return if balanced and not nested ?

Answer (score -1):

def solution (S):
B =[]

```
if len(S) == 0:
    return 1
for i in range (0,len(S)):
    if S[i] == "(" or S[i] == "[" or S[i] == "{":
        B.append(S[i])
    else: 
        return 0
    if (S[i] == ")" and B[-1]!= "(") :
        return 0
    if (S[i] == "}" and B[-1]!= "{") :
        return 0
    if (S[i] == "]" and B[-1]!= "[") :
        return 0
    else:
        B.pop()
if len(B)==0:   
        return 1
```

This is causing issue,Because initially length of B is 0,So as loop starts at i=0 len(B) == 0 and returning 1.

Try to place it out of the loop.

Comment: No this doesn't work either. I got wrong answer for brackets that was nested correctly.